# Table attribute displayed

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I use Entity Framework in my project.

```
[Table("GetInfo")]
public class InDetails : IEntityWithRelationships
{
    [Required]
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Primary Key", Description = "Primary Key")]
    [Editable(false)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Pkey { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Facility ID", Description = "Facility ID is located at")]
    public int FacilityID { get; set; }

    public String Photo { get; set; }
```

You see some have [Required]/[Displayed], but some not.
What is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ones without attributes are not required, in the case of `[Required]`.  In the case of `[Display(Name =)]` this tells the consuming UI layer what the displayed name and description should be.  For properties with out the `[Display]` attribute, the property name is what gets displayed.